# NASA's GIBS WMTS servers with Mapbox GLJS

Tags: mapbox, wmts, mapbox-gl-js, nasa

I want to use WMTS Vector Tiles with Mapbox GL JS. The points on the map are displayed but slightly off as you can see are the points for Africa in the ocean.

The tiles URL is from the GIBS tutorial page: https://nasa-gibs.github.io/gibs-api-docs/access-advanced-topics/#vector-visualizations

In the URL I can see epsg4326 which means that the tiles are in the correct format for Mapbox Map because the Mapbox map renders in EPSG:3857 but needs EPSG:4326 to work with; correct me if I am wrong.

Any ideas?

```
map.addSource("thermal_anomalies", {
    type: "vector",
    tiles: [https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All/default/2020-10-01T00:00:00Z/500m/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt],
});

map.addLayer({
    'id': 'thermal_anomalies-layer',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'thermal_anomalies',
    "source-layer": "VIIRS_NOAA20_Thermal_Anomalies_375m_All_v2_NRT",
    'layout': {
        'visibility': 'visible'
    },
    'paint': {
        'circle-radius': {
            'base': 1.75,
            'stops': [
                [12, 2], // at level 12
                [22, 180] // at level 22
            ]
        },
        'circle-color': "#f0c94a"
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: If you need EPSG:3857 you can't use the WMTS according to the documentation ~ https://nasa-gibs.github.io/gibs-api-docs/access-advanced-topics/#wmts-vector-tiles  If Mapbox GLJS only supports epsg:3857 then you won't be able to use the epsg:4326 WMTS, they are different CRS

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/57385901 says that Mapbox needs 4326 but renders in 3857. I see that the tiles are served with wmts/epsg4326 right?

Comment: The post you are referring to talks about markers and GeoJSON layers data, but you have have vector tiles.

Comment: These are comments, not answers.  The post mentions GeoJSON, but GeoJSON isn't epsg:4326 it's CRS:84 (epsg:4326 has axes of lat/long GeoJSON has axes of long/lat).